# Could binomial probability be used as an approximation in this scenario?

Tags: probability

Using recent climatological data, you could find that NYC has about a 20% chance of experiencing a major blizzard with more than 18 inches of snow on any given year.  Suppose you want to find the probability that five such blizzards will happen in the next decade.  I suppose you could let $n = 10$, $p = 0.2$, $q = 0.8$ and $r = 5$ and then $P(r = 5) =$ $10 \choose 5$ $(0.2)^5(0.8)^5$.  The obvious problem is that NYC can have more than one major blizzard per year, thus $r$ could be larger than $n$.  Could binomial probability still serve as an approximation, or is it completely wrong?

As a second question, how would we handle such a problem in the proper way?

Comment: Hopefully you found my solution below helpful; if so would you please consider accepting it. Stack exchange sites survive by people donating their time to helping people, and accepting / upvoting is a easy way to give back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the scenario in which more than one blizzard occurs in a year then you may wish to consider using a [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) distribution.

The appropriateness of this as a model depends on how willing you are to accept that the blizzards occur independently.

Recall that if $B$ (the number of blizzards in a year) is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda > 0$ then

$$\mathbf P[B = n] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}.$$

I will interpret your statement of "20% chance of experiencing a major blizzard with more than 18 inches of snow on any given year" to mean that there is a 20% chance of at least one such event happening (though perhaps you meant a 20% chance of exactly one?). Therefore

$$\mathbf P[B = 0] = e^{-\lambda} = 0.8,$$

from which we can solve for $\lambda = -\log \frac{4}{10}$.

If we denote $B_y$ for the number of blizzards in year $y = 1,\ldots, 10$ and suppose that the distribution of blizzards does not change over the period, and that each year is independent then $B_y \sim \text{Poi}(\lambda)$ for each $y$.

Moreover since sums of independent Poisson variables are also Poisson, we have

$$\sum_{y =1}^{10} B_y \sim \text{Poi}(10\lambda)$$

So in particular the probability of five blizzards in the period is

$$\mathbf P \left[ \textstyle \sum_{y=1}^{10} B_y = 5\right] = e^{-10 \lambda} \frac{(10 \lambda)^5}{5!} \sim 0.0495, $$

where we used $\lambda = -\log \frac{4}{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

As you yourself have indicated, more than one blizzard could happen per year. If there is a very low probability of that happening, you *could* try to model the scenario as a binomial distribution.

Binomial distributions only fit [Bernoulli trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)—i.e. events that are either true or not, they can take only two values. If by

> NYC has about a 20% chance of experiencing a major blizzard with more
>   than 18 inches of snow on any given year

you mean that the probability of *at least one* such blizzard occurring in a year is 20%, then it *is* a Bernoulli trial. If, instead, by that you mean that the probability of *exactly one* such blizzard occurring in a year is 20%, then it is *not* a Bernoulli trial, and thus should *not* be modelled as a binomial distribution.

A [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) would then be the best statistical distribution to model the scenario (see [owen8's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2697702/326036)).